# Apache unable to load perl module

Tags: apache, perl, httpd.conf

I am experimenting with setting up an Apache server and running some perl scripts on it, but I'm running into some issues with my Apache and Perl config.

Initially, I was getting a 500 server error when trying to run a cgi script, and the error log showed that Apache was looking in the wrong @INC for a module I was running.

So, in `httpd.conf`, I added this line:

`SetEnv PERL5LIB /Users/rasha/.plenv/versions/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-2level:/Users/rasha/.plenv/versions/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0:/Users/rasha/.plenv/versions/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0/darwin-2level:/Users/rasha/.plenv/versions/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0`

which I got by running: `perl -e 'print join "\n", @INC;'`

Now I am still getting a 500 server error, but with a different error message:

`[Tue Feb 22 14:24:32.919661 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 35434] [client 127.0.0.1:55187] AH01215: Can't load '/Users/rasha/.plenv/versions/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle' for module List::Util: dlopen(/Users/rasha/.plenv/versions/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle, 0x0001): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PL_DBsub' at /Users/rasha/.plenv/versions/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0/XSLoader.pm line 96.: /usr/local/var/www/cgi-bin/test`

The `test` script I am trying to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use CGI qw(:standard);

my ($dbh, $sth, $count);

$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:host=localhost;database=xxxx", 
                    "xxxx", "xxxx",
                    {PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1});

$sth = $dbh->prepare("Select name, wins, losses from teams");
$sth->execute;

print header, start_html("team data");
$count = 0;

while (my @val = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
  print p (sprintf ("name = %s, wins = %d, losses = %d\n", $val[0], $val[1], $val[2]));
  $count++;
};

print p("$count rows total"), end_html;
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

Does anyone have any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Your CGI script is probably run by apache using the system perl. But your modules was installed with a different perl installed by plenv, this is probably why loading the xs module fail. Can you try change the shebang line of the CGI script to the absolute path to the plenv-installed perl ? (The output of running `which perl` in the terminal)

Comment: That seems like a reasonable explanation. But when I change the hash bang to
`/Users/rasha/.plenv/versions/5.34.0/bin/perl`

I get a 500 server error and this message:
`[Tue Feb 22 18:02:11.247968 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 36958] [client 127.0.0.1:56561] AH01215: (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/local/var/www/cgi-bin/intro7' failed: /usr/local/var/www/cgi-bin/test`

which indicates to me that the perl version is not recognized at all

Comment: `ENOEXEC` (8, "Exec format error") means "An executable is not in a recognized format, is for the wrong architecture, or has some other format error that means it cannot be executed.". What's the output of `file /usr/local/var/www/cgi-bin/intro7` and of `head -n 1/usr/local/var/www/cgi-bin/intro7`?

Comment: Note that after fixing the shebang, there should be no need to set PERL5LIB

Comment: the output of `file /usr/local/var/www/cgi-bin/intro7` is:  
`/usr/local/var/www/cgi-bin/intro7: Perl script text executable`  

and `head -n 1/usr/local/var/www/cgi-bin/intro7`:  
`#!/Users/rasha/.plenv/versions/5.34.0/bin/perl`

Comment: It worked after both fixing the shebang and removing the PERL5LIB from httpd.conf. Keeping the SetEnv was the issue. Thanks all!